# Prefect: How to imperatively create tasks based on a task list derived from a Parameter

Tags: python, prefect

I'm trying to define tasks imperatively based on a list. The challenge is that the list should be based on a Prefect parameter.

Below is the code I tried, but apparently it doesn't work as task_dependency_pairs is a task, not a list.

How do I make it work without breaking the dependency between the Parameter task, and the other dynamically generated tasks?

```
from prefect import task, Flow, Parameter, Task
import time

@task
def task_dependency_pairs(param):
    return [
    ('task 1', f'{param}A', ''),
    ('task 2', f'{param}B','task 1'),
    ('task 3', f'{param}C','task 1')]

class Task_class(Task):

    def run(self, **kwarg):   
        time.sleep(5)
        print(f"This task {kwarg['task_name']} does a lot of things with {kwarg.get('calc_value','')}.")

for task_name, dependency in task_dependency_pairs:
    globals()[task_name] = type(task_name, (Task_class,),{"__module__": __name__})

with Flow("my_process") as flow:

    param = Parameter("param", default="default_param")
    task_dependency_pairs_list = task_dependency_pairs(param)
    for task_name, calc_value, dependency in task_dependency_pairs_list:   # This won't work
        task_instance = globals()[task_name](name=task_name)
        flow.add_task(task_instance(task_name = task_name, calc_value = calc_value))

    for task_name, calc_value, dependency in task_dependency_pairs_list:  # This won't work
        if len(dependency) >0:
            flow.get_tasks(name=task_name)[0].set_upstream(flow.get_tasks(name=dependency)[0])

flow.visualize()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to dynamically create tasks in a prefect Flow is best managed [via the mapping functionality.](https://docs.prefect.io/core/concepts/mapping.html)

However, the mapping simply will generate tasks from an iterable during the flow run. It doesn't arbitrarily tweak dependencies of the generated tasks; they all share the dependencies as defined on the main `mapped` task.

However, if you wanted to generate a flow at runtime (with programmatic dependencies), the only way I can think of would be to create a task that creates a flow and immediately runs it.

The way this might look for your flow is:

```
...

@task
def run_flow(inputs):
    with Flow("subflow") as sub_flow:
        for (name, calc_value, dependency) in inputs:
            inst = Task_class(name=name)(task_name=name, calc_value=calc_value)
            sub_flow.add_task(inst)
            if dependency:
                inst.set_upstream(sub_flow.get_tasks(name=dependency)[0])

    sub_flow.run()

with Flow("my_process") as flow:
    param = Parameter("param", default="default_param")
    task_dependency_pairs_list = task_dependency_pairs(param)
    run_flow(task_dependency_pairs_list)
```